# Change image Src only while animating its margin-left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

For a browser game purpose i want to change an image src to an animated gif only while the image is being animated.

> $(the_image_selector).animate({marginLeft: amount}, time);

How can i do it?

My idea is to change the image to the gif before calling animate, then use animate's callback to change back the image. Will it work?

Comment: `My idea is to change the image to the gif before calling animate, then use animate's callback to change back the image. Will it work?` - yes! try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I do think your strategy will work, for example

```
var image = $(the_image_selector);

image.attr('src', 'url to show while animated');

image.animate({marginLeft: amount}, time, function(){
    image.attr('src', 'normal url');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can run function then animation is complet. from jquery.com

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).css('background-image','any-image.gif');
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
  }, 5000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
     $( "#book" ).css('background-image','any-image.png');
  });
});
```

Comment: if combine my and you answer it will be good). after animation  complete he's need to change img back(png -> gif -> png)

Comment: thx! but @Andreas and you give more correctly answers, cause user1190288 ask about img tag directly, and not about bg-image). to topic-starter and all others - its better use bg-image, so u can collect images into one big sprite, and just change bg-position. In this case, the sprite is fully loaded, and will not flicker due to load the image

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$(the_image_selector).css('background-image','path-to-image');
$(the_image_selector).animate({marginLeft: amount}, time);
```

Or, combine like this:

```
$(the_image_selector).css('background-image','path-to-image').animate({marginLeft: amount}, time);
```

Or, if you want to change img's src then:

```
$(the_image_selector).attr('src','path-to-image').animate({marginLeft: amount}, time);
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdBpH/)

As noted in my comment this will work:

```
var src = $('img').attr('src');
$('img').attr('src', 'https://disney-animation.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/production/project_image/frozen/72/image/project_image.jpg');
$('img').animate({
    marginLeft: '100px'
}, 2000, function () {
    $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```